# AngularJS: why does $scope data not persist over a ui-router state change?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, persistent-storage

I have two views, each with a controller, each representing a UI-Router state.

If I set `$scope` variables in one controller, change state away, then back, the variables no longer contain the values assigned.

I can persist data over state changes by using as service to store it, so my code is working.

I imagine that each time `ui-router` switches state it destroys the object of the old state and instantiates an object of the new state.

I am just curious as to why things were designed this way. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the idea behind AngularJS controllers with routing is that they're related only to the objects that are currently being used. A route in this case is seen as a node in a tree, and if you traverse from any one node to any other non-child node, then assuming that the old data is still relevant might be illogical. However, if you do navigate through child states, then it becomes logical again to save the data.

---

*Example*

Suppose you have an app that looks like a social media site. You have a `feed` state with a list of messages, a `create` state to add your own post, and `contacts` app. This latter one has a child state to list contacts (`contacts.list`) and one to view single contacts (`contacts.view`):

```
feed -------- create -------- contacts
                           ______|______
                          /             \
                         /               \
                        /                 \
                  contacts.list     contacts.view
```

Scrolling through a feed, if you decide to create your own message, and then want to go back to your feed, you might want to show where you left off. However, that would require storing loaded posts and comments in memory, along with the position on the page and loaded images. Since your feed is dynamic, and already viewed posts are probably not shown again, it might be more logical to just refresh the feed and start over.

By contrast, if you go to the contacts page - and are thus rerouted to `contacts.list`, those entries are probably sorted, be it alphabetical or by date added. If you scroll through and decide to view a contact, the ordering will hopefully be the same when you come back, and you probably won't have any new contacts, so it's better to resume where you left off. This can be done by loading the list of contacts into the parent state, potentially with the ID of the last viewed contact, to see where you were. An example of this might be the breadcrumb element, which indicates a path in a tree of potential paths.

If you move from one state to the other, you create a path between nodes, say you *leave* `create` to *enter* `feed`, or you *enter* `contacts` and subsequently `contacts.list`. If you move from `contacts.view` to `contacts.list`, you *retain* `contacts` and thus that controller stays in use - it is never destroyed.

---

*Moving back in history vs normal navigation*

There is an important distinction being left out here, though, which is the difference between moving back through the backwards arrow in a mobile app, or through the back button on your browser. This contrasts with clicking the button to go to the home page in that it assumes that the homepage was already loaded in the past.

In many mobile apps, navigation is seen as a flow, and large menus are avoided when possible. Instead, much focus is put on creating a history, so pages that were previously visited can be revisited, no matter where in the tree they were, by swiping left or always clicking the same button. In addition, with mobile apps, a solid network connection cannot be assumed, so it's considered better to keep an old page as-is, than it is to refresh and refetch from the server. This is also the reason why AngularJS based frameworks like Ionic provide specific page history features.